# Stochastic %D values above 80 and below 20

Tags: pine-script, stochastic

Here is a simple script I wrote to indicate a simple reversal pattern. I want to add to each line so when the stochastic %D is higher than 80 will trigger a red down arrow and when %D is below 20 trigger a green up arrow.

```
study("Ringed HL", overlay=true)
datadown = open[1] > open[2] and close[1] > close[2] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close < open
dataup =  open[1] < open[2] and close[1] < close[2] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close > open
plotshape(datadown, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)
plotshape(dataup, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.
I've added a checkbox input to show all arrows below/above the threshold.
If unchecked, it'll only show the first arrow when it crosses the treshold.

```
//@version=4
study("Ringed HL", overlay=true)

Length          = input (14, minval=1, title = "Stochastic Length")
k               = input ( 1, minval=1, title = "Stochastic %K")
d               = input ( 5, minval=1, title = "Stochastic %D")
showAll         = input(false)

sto             = stoch (close, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
K               = sma (sto, k)
D               = sma (sto, d)


D_over_80       = D > 80
D_under_20      = D < 20

show_D_over_80  = showAll ? D_over_80  : D_over_80  != D_over_80[1]  ? D_over_80  : na 
show_D_under_20 = showAll ? D_under_20 : D_under_20 != D_under_20[1] ? D_under_20 : na 

plotshape(show_D_over_80,  style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)
plotshape(show_D_under_20, style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.belowbar, color=color.green)
```

Update: Code integrated with original question code.

```
//@version=4
study("Ringed HL", overlay=true)

Length          = input (14, minval=1, title = "Stochastic Length")
k               = input ( 1, minval=1, title = "Stochastic %K")
d               = input ( 5, minval=1, title = "Stochastic %D")
showAll         = input(false)

sto             = stoch (close, highest(Length), lowest(Length), Length)
K               = sma (sto, k)
D               = sma (sto, d)

D_over_80       = D > 80
D_under_20      = D < 20

datadown        = open[1] > open[2] and close[1] > close[2] and close[2] > open[2] and close[1] > open[1] and close < open
dataup          = open[1] < open[2] and close[1] < close[2] and close[2] < open[2] and close[1] < open[1] and close > open

show_datadown   = datadown and D_over_80
show_dataup     = dataup   and D_under_20

plotshape(show_datadown, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)
plotshape(show_dataup, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green)
```

Comment: Thank you! Getting there but the script I posted above works but I only want the arrows to show when the stochastic conditions are met. i.e., D > 80 for datadown and D < 20 for dataup. Just need to add what you did to the original somehow.

Comment: Oh, so you want your `dataup` and `datadown` arrows to be shown only when D>80 and D<20 ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with my code integrated in yours. If that's not what you wanted, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question.

Did you call for stochastic?

```
X= stoch(source, high, low, length)
```